# Numbers appearing below figures when using gb4e

Tags: spacing, floats, numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I'm trying to number my figures in Latex, and in linguistics it's conventional for the number to appear above the figure. It's also conventional for all tables, figures and examples to receive the same numbering, which is why I haven't used the caption. Unfortunately, in my case the number always appears below the figure as opposed to above. I'm using the gb4e package for numbering. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \ex
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.86\textwidth]{Life_Cycle.PNG}
    \label{lifecycle}
\end{figure}
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This produces ...

[image]

As you can see the number is below the figure. Taking the \ex command out of the figure environment is a quick fix, but then the number may appear separately to the figure depending on placement, which is a pain.

Does anyone know how this might be fixed?

Many thanks.

Comment: it doesn't look to be below the figure but rather on the same line, to the left, put a pargarph break (blank line) after `\ex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `\ex` on the same line as the figure so aligned with its baseline, you can place it in a paragraph above, for example

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \ex\mbox{}

    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.86\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{lifecycle}
\end{figure}
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works great. I have a quick follow-up question if I may: do you know how to keep the numbering within the page margins? Thanks!

Comment: that would be the default the `\ex` command of the package is presumably setting in the margin by design. might be better to ask a  new question about that someone who knows the package could answer rather than me looking at the source and hacking something

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.